# std::optional with Eigen::ArrayBase

Tags: templates, generics, option-type, eigen3

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
std::optional<Eigen::Array<typename Derived::Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>>
function1(const std::optional<Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>>& opt1,
     const std::optional<Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>>& opt2)
{

}
```

how to write this kind of template with Eigen::ArrayBase so that it can accept two Array or Matrix or nullopt

like:

```cpp
ArrayXXd a(4, 3);
ArrayXXd b(4, 3);
auto q = function1(a,b);
```

I know I can do this:

```cpp
function2(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived1>& opt1,
          const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived2>& opt2)
{
}
```

Comment: C++ can't do automatic template deduction and type conversion at the same time. What do you actually want? Would overloading be an option?

Comment: Yes now I know it, overloading will work. I was just curious why it won't work when I tried to use template in optional... now I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against it but with some helper functions it can be made to work.

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <functional>
// using std::cref, std::reference_wrapper

template<class Derived>
using optional_const_array_ref =
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>>>;

template<class Derived>
optional_const_array_ref<Derived>
make_optional_const_array(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& arr) noexcept
{ return std::cref(arr); }

template <typename Derived>
void function1(optional_const_array_ref<Derived> opt1)
{
    if(opt1)
        std::cout << opt1->get().transpose() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::Array3d b(1., 2., 3.);
    function1(make_optional_const_array(b + 1.));
}
```

The reasons why this is hard:

- `optional` contains its content by-value. You cannot use it with an abstract class
- You expect too much from the type deduction rules
- We create what could easily become a dangling pointer. C++ is mighty unsafe in this regard but at least parts of it are designed to prevent you from doing it

Several caveats:

1. You cannot use `option->` to access the array inside. You have to go the extra step of using `reference_wrapper::get()`
2. Under absolutely no circumstances can you extend the lifetime of that `optional` or its content. This all seems like a recipe for creating dangling pointers
3. What derived type should an empty `optional` have? You have to define *some* type but you can't necessarily use every type in Eigen. For one, you create an extra template instantiation, which will just waste a lot of compiled code size. Also, you might trigger static assertions and other compile time issues, for example if the scalar type is different from the ones you expect. You probably have to define the type explicitly per call site. E.g. `function1(optional_const_array<Eigen::Array3d>{})`

Did I already mention that I don't think this is a good idea? Because I don't think this is a good idea.

### Alternative

There is very little advantage in an optional reference wrapper compared to a plain pointer. We might as well do this:

```cpp
template<class Derived>
const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>*
make_ptr(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& arr) noexcept
{ return &arr; }

template <typename Derived>
void function2(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>* opt1)
{
    if(opt1)
        std::cout << opt1->transpose() << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    Eigen::Array3d b(1., 2., 3.);
    function2(make_ptr(b + 1));
    function2<Eigen::Array3d>(nullptr);
}
```

It's just as unsafe as the reference wrapper but it's cheaper and shorter code. The moment you extend the lifetime of that pointer beyond the expression in which `make_ptr` is called, you have a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Indeed, template in optional is not a good idea. I will try other methods.